# Python - from . import

Tags: python, import, relative-path

I'm taking my first stab at a library, and I've noticed the easiest way to solve the issue of intra-library imports is by using constructions like the following:

```
from . import x
from ..some_module import y
```

Something about this strikes me as 'bad.'  Maybe it's just the fact that I can't remember seeing it very often, although in fairness I haven't poked around the guts of a ton of libraries.

Just wanted to see if this is considered good practice and, if not, what's the better way to do this?

Comment: The [Google Python Styleguide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Imports) doesn't like it, I personally do. *Meh*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a PEP for everything.

Quote from [PEP8: Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

> Explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports, especially when dealing with complex package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily verbose:

[Guido's decision](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) in [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) *Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative*

### Copy Pasta from PEP328

Here's a sample package layout:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        moduleZ.py
    moduleA.py
```

Assuming that the current file is either `moduleX.py` or `subpackage1/__init__.py` , the following are all correct usages of the new syntax:

```
from .moduleY import spam
from .moduleY import spam as ham
from . import moduleY
from ..subpackage1 import moduleY
from ..subpackage2.moduleZ import eggs
from ..moduleA import foo
from ...package import bar
from ...sys import path
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicit is better than implicit. At least according to the zen of python.

I find using . based imports to be confusing especially if you build or work in lots of libraries. If I don't know the package structure by heart its going to be less obvious where something comes from this way.

If someone wants to do something similar to (but not the same as) what I'm doing inside one of my library's modules, if the full package structure is specified in the import, people can copy and paste the import line.

Refactoring and restructuring are more difficult with dots because they will mean something different if you move a module around in a package structure or if you move a module to a different package.

If you want convenient access to something in your package, its likely other people do to, so you might as well solve that problem by building a good library rather than leaning on the language to keep your import lines under 80 characters. In these cases, if you have a package `mypackage` with sub package `stuff` with module `things` and class `Whatever` needs to be imported frequently in your code and users code, you can put an import in to the `__init__.py` for `mypackage`:

```
__all__ = ['Whatever']
from mypackage.stuff.things import Whatever
```

and then you and anyone else who wants to use `Whatever` can just do:

```
from mypackage import Whatever
```

But getting less verbose or less explicit than that will more than likely cause you or someone else difficulty down the line.

Comment: It was kind of a judgement call as to whether I accepted this answer or Yanniks since they are both well thought out, despite disagreeing... I went with his on the strength of the appeal to PEP8.  I appreciate these thoughts as well though and will try some of these methods out.

Comment: I appreciate the comment - good feedback helps me craft better and more helpful answers :-) ... I do think there is a place for explicitly relative imports, but since you mentioned library development I do think developers using your library benefit from the self documentation offered by the self documenting nature of not using relative notation. In client code and scripts all is fair game, but I would definitely encourage you if you develop for developers not to be afraid of wordiness where it adds to understanding whats going on.