# python modules import confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this file structure

```
project
├── src
    ├── main
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── app.py
        ├── constants.py
    └── test
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_commands.py
```

inside `app.py`, I import `constants.py` using `import constants`. This will work fine if I run `python3 app.py`
Inside `test_commands.py` I have `from main import app`, this will correctly import it, however it will error on:

```
File .../src/main/app.py", line 4, in <module>
import constants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'
```

But, if I switch that line to `from main import constants`, then it will work. However, now `python3 app.py` no longer works:

```
File .../src/main/app.py", line 4, in <module>
from main import constants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

How do I fix this so both cases will work? Is that even possible? What is the proper way to import modules in this case?

Comment: `main` is a package. Without telling Python where `constants` is (i.e. inside `main`), it can't figure out where to import from. That's a good thing.

Comment: It's better to run `python -m main.app` from inside the `src/` directory. Fun fact: if you provide a `__main__.py` file, you can even do `python -m main` to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting relative imports from within a module, try using

```py
import .constants
```

instead of

```py
import constants
```

Note the `.`, which indicates that you are importing from a local file within the module, specifically from the same directory.

This works with `from` imports as well. For instance,

```py
from . import constants
```

Take a look at these resources for more information:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules
- [Python - from . import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283139/python-from-import)

Comment: "from . import constants" gives a 
"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"
and "import .constants" gives a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"